# Fluid image, vertical align (middle) within width fluid DIV

Tags: css, image, vertical-alignment

So yet another question about vertically aligning an image within a div, but I think mine is different than the others I've found on here. I can't seem to find a solution that works for my situation.

I have a DIV that is 100% width (to it's container, which is floating left and has a set pixel width) and has a set pixel height. I have an image inside that I am positioning absolute to get it to the background of content within the DIV. The image is fluid with a width of 100%.

All works well, but I want to get the image to vertically align to the middle of the container and height is unknown.

Here is some sample code that shows what I'm trying to do:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4111/4968056789_d872094672_o.jpg" 
       width="100%" />
  </div>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

And some sample CSS:

```
.container {
  width:100%;
  margin-top:10px;

  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.image-wrapper > img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

But the flower should show up with it's center visible within the container div.

Any thoughts? I'm trying to avoid any Javascript sizing (the outer container, not shown in this sample, is already being sized). I'm not opposed to more DIVs, tables.. whatever you got!

A jsFiddle to demo this:
http://jsfiddle.net/JonMcL/sNz9h/

Answer (score 4):

Why not go for the background-image property? That allows vertical centering...

http://jsfiddle.net/urrWS/

Comment: snap got in 2 seconds before me

Comment: @DominicGreen yep i noticed, gave you +1 but for some reason someone else downvoted - which is a shame, your example is even simpler..

Comment: yer not sure why got down vote its annoying when people down vote and dont comment why

Comment: But it doesn't allow for image scaling. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: No image scaling, i'm afraid - unless you can use ccs3 - ccs3 includes the background-size property...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to only scale the image down and not stretch it beyond its native resolution this should do the trick. A little bit of jQuery is involved but it's minimal. Essentially, this adjusts the top-margin of the IMG on the window.resize event.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="image.jpg"> <!-- native size is 480x300 -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

#image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

jQuery

```
function adjustImage() {
    $("#image").css('margin-top', ($("#container").height() - $("#image").height()) / 2);
}

$(window).load(function() {
    adjustImage();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustImage();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get what you need I would suggest setting the background image via css, then you can set the position correctly etc.

```
.container {
width:100%;
margin-top:10px;
background-image:url("http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4111/4968056789_d872094672_o.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:left center;
height:100px;
overflow:hidden;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/sNz9h/6/

Comment: Image width is 100% of container so that it scales. Background-image won't do that.